# method invokes a dynamically generated LDAP filter with unvalidated i/p

Tags: java, fortify

I am getting the below critical risk while scanning through Fortify tool.

method getUserLDAPNameFromAD() invokes a dynamically generated LDAP filter with unvalidated input,which could allow an attacker to modify the statement's meaning.

in class: ConsoleService

```
public class ConsoleService implements IConsoleService {
public char[] readPassword() throws IOError {
    return System.console().readPassword();
}
 and 

 public final class ConsoleUtils {

public static final String TERMINATION_CHARACTER = ".";
private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

being used in LDAPservice.java class i am getting LDAP injection error.
in below code lines:

public Attribute getUserLDAPNameFromAD(LDAPUserAttribute attribute) throws NamingException {

```
    String accountName = attribute.constructName(Constants.DOT, true);
    EqualsFilter equalsFilter = new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", accountName);
    String FILTER = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(" + equalsFilter.toString() + "))";
    SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
    ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(base, FILTER, ctls);
    if (answer.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult result = answer.next();
        return result.getAttributes().get("distinguishedName");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Anybody having any idea how can i resolve this?

Comment: Hi Michael,     Is this EqualsFilter restricts unvalidated characters or we have to use encode method to the filter results to get it safe? We have used parameterized LDAP filter only, my bad i have forgot to attach the code for that.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this since it wasn't a comment to my answer. [EqualsFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/ldap/filter/EqualsFilter.html) is a part of Spring and it's designed to escape LDAP strings, but it isn't clear to me that it's designed to be used directly with JNDI. I'd say it will probably work and probably be ok, but if you wanted to be safe I'd switch to the syntax in my answer which bypasses Spring and uses native JNDI.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the error you're getting in your static analysis tool you should use parameterized LDAP filters instead of doing string concatenation like you're doing. The risk with string concatenation is that a malicious user can potentially abuse the LDAP filter syntax to either always match, or always not match, which oftentimes has security implications in your application.

It looks like you're using Spring's EqualsFilter, which may properly escape the string. But the static analysis tool isn't acknowledging it.

To use parameterized LDAP filters you can do the following ([as described in the JNDI tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/result.html)):

```
ctx.search(base,
    "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))",
    new Object[] { accountName },
    ctls);
```